# Firebase Authentication via Server Side to access routes

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am using sessionStorage and also firebase authentication for email and password.

In my server.js I am wondering how can I make it so that if a user is not logged in they cannot access a route, or rather be redirected to the login route instead.
The firebase sdk I am using is only usable via the client side. Is there any documentation to help that I have been unable to find.

*Please let me know if I need to clarify my question more and I will do my best to do so.*

Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const path = require('path');

let serviceAccount = require("./1234.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

let staticPath = path.join(__dirname,"public");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(staticPath));
app.use(express.json());

    app.get('/login', (req,res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, "form.html"));
    })
    
    app.get('/seller', (req,res) => {
    // if(!user) res.redirect('/login');
        res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, "seller.html"));
    })
```

Edit:
So far the only thing that helps me with this is by creating a seller.js
and inserting this code here, but I am unsure of if this method is safe or if there is a way to hide this from being manipulated:

```
body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.user);
if(user && user.seller){
    console.log('Allow Access')
} else{
    console.log('Deny')
    body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="sticky" id="nav"></div>
    <div style="padding:300px">
    <center>You do not have permission to view this page.</center>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    `;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `firebase-admin` package to verify the token on the server. If the verification passes, you can continue with route logic. To make things simple, you could wire up a middleware in Express that verifies the token, rather than repeating the calls for authenticated routes.

Relevant documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web

Also, you should not rely on client-side scripting to verify a user's authentication status if you're trying to restrict resources on a server. It would be trivial for someone to find the endpoints being used, and, assuming there's no logic on the server to verify the user, they could potentially retrieve sensitive information.